# How to use redis in windows?

Tags: node.js, npm, redis, node-modules, redis-cluster

I want to use redis in my nodejs application.I have installed npm package for redis. But while starting application i am getting error as

```
 Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

Comment: Have you installed & started the redis server too?! BTW, I dont think you can do this. redis has only releases for Linux OSs

Comment: i have not installed redis server. Do we have any other option ?

Comment: Short answer, No. "Long" answer, install a linux VM.

Comment: Just use docker. `docker run -p 6379:6379 redis`

Answer (score 0):

Install WSL on windows. Can do this through Microsoft store. Example below is using Ubuntu and assumes you have installed the distribution with an open terminal. Ubuntu can be started by normal ways of starting applications on Windows.

```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get upgrade
> sudo apt-get install redis-server
> redis-cli -v
```

This performs updates to ubuntu on your machine and installs redis.

The last command should output something like: `redis-cli 6.2.5`

If for some reason redis is not running, execute `sudo service redis-server restart` in ubuntu terminal